# nested loop with same index name

Tags: swift

In the below nested loop:

```
for i in 0..<2 {
    print(i)
    for i in 0..<2 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

the output should be:

0
0
1

However it produces:

0
0
1
1
0
1
I can't find anything referring to the scope of the index (i) in apple documentations. I would appreciate any reference or explanation from an official source.

Comment: why don't you change your inner loop var name

Comment: Well, excusing how blatantly poor the code is (nobody would do this, we all know that), the results show exactly what you are thinking - each loop has it's own variable scope. I'm surprised too. If this is indeed what you're thinking, a few thoughts: (1) What if instead of "for i in" you did for arrayElement in" with nested arrays of the same type? Does this same behavior happen? (2) You've done your research for sure, is this worthy of a swift.org query/request? BOTTOM LINE: Good catch on the behavior! Now, unless you **really** wish to confuse your "future self" use a different index. :-)

Comment: Why is it surprising that each loop has its own variable scope? The loop introduces a new variable binding. You could also do `for let i` which makes that more obvious.

Comment: this question is not about a problem I am facing in a code. It is to understand why swift is considering i as two different vars. that will not be the case with Java for example.

Comment: @dfd thank you for the comment, I was reading this repo and found a nested loop with the same index name :) , I agree it was confusing.https://github.com/vinceyuan/WatchTicTacToe/blob/master/WatchTicTacToeSwift/WatchTicTacToe%20WatchKit%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift

Comment: @jtbandes, see my comment in one of the answer. It's **very** surprising, because it's *not intuitive* to many of us who have been programming for decades in other languages. I'm not complaining (well, except for clarity in code maintenance) but am saying this behavior - which may have existed since June 2014 - is something I wouldn't have expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a loop `for X in ...`, you're defining scope that exists during each iteration and a constant that exists in that scope.  I can't find explicit documentation of scope except for in the case of `do {}` but the documentation does assume scope is created and destroyed in loops when speaking of things like the `guard` declaration.  In practice, this is what the scope for `i` in a single loop looks like.

```
// Scope that i doesn't exist in.

for i in 1..<2 {
    // Scope that i exists in.
}

// Scope that i doesn't exist in.
```

When defining a nested scope (which your inner for loop is), you have the ability to redefine variables and constants.  This is what happens when you define `i` in the loop declaration.  Inside the inner loop, the compiler looks outward through the scope for definitions.

In the case of `i`, it looks in the inner loop and finds it.  In the case of `print`, the identifier used, it looks in the inner loop, the outer loop, any containing fiction, then class, then module, then imported modules until it finds `Swift.print`.

Comment: How is the example explaining the i in the outer loop is invisible in the inner loop?

Comment: I **still** am surprised. Sure, my formal education was between 1976-98. But this is not something at all intuitive. Explicit documentation is needed. That said, (and please if doc is found, add it) I like your explanation. Up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop variables are scoped to the body of the loop. Swift allows shadowing of local variables, so the nested loop gets a brand-new variable called "i", and loses access to variable "i" from its outer scope.

Comment: That's what i was thinking about. But is there an official source to this?

Comment: Commenting here because you have more rep. This behavior **feels** very wrong. (It's true though.) What I mean to say is when I learned about variable scope some 40 years ago, loops didn't operate that way. While I understand that my comment here is mostly opinion, this is something I would not expect - in fact, a certification (yeah yeah, MSFT) I received 20 years ago tested exactly on this and at the very least needed "more" to communicate to everyone that you **are not** tromping on things with each loop. Very surprising behavior to me....

Comment: @iShaalan That has to be in the language reference. I don't have access to it at the moment (I'm on a mobile device) but it should be in the chapter about loops.

Comment: @dfd Coming from C background myself, I find this behavior grossly counterintuitive.